# get checked text from checkable combobox in Pyqt5

Tags: qt, checkbox, pyqt5, qcombobox

i'm trying to collect text of checked items from custom combobox created with checkbox in pyqt5.

Here's my workable snippet which is not printing selected texts as per my expectation:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class CheckableComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

    def checkedItems(self):
        checkedItems = []
        for index in range(self.count()):
            item = self.item(index)
            if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                checkedItems.append(item)
        return checkedItems

class Ui_dialogCreateBatch(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialogCreateBatch):
        dialogCreateBatch.resize(400, 338)
        dialogCreateBatch.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(dialogCreateBatch)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 360, 115))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.cboItemList = CheckableComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.cboItemList.setObjectName("cboItemList")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.cboItemList, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        data = ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
        for index, element in enumerate(data):
            self.cboItemList.addItem(element)
            item = self.cboItemList.model().item(index, 0)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(dialogCreateBatch)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 300, 156, 23))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(dialogCreateBatch)

        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(dialogCreateBatch.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialogCreateBatch)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialogCreateBatch):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        dialogCreateBatch.setWindowTitle(_translate("dialogCreateBatch", "Create Item Batch"))

    def accept(self):
        selectedItems = self.cboItemList.checkedItems()
        print(selectedItems)
        dialogCreateBatch.close

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialogCreateBatch = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_dialogCreateBatch()
    ui.setupUi(dialogCreateBatch)
    dialogCreateBatch.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the above code i have added print line for logging returned data. but i;m not receiving any data returned from here

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case when I executed your code I could not see the `QCheckBox`, the solution was to establish a `QListView` to the `view()` of the `QComboBox`.

The biggest mistake I see is that in the following expression `self.cboMulSup.checkedItems()` you are trying to access `cboMulSup` but you have never defined it.

On the other hand it is not recommended to modify the code generated by Qt Designer, PyQt I recommend to create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the class `Ui_xxx`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class CheckableComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setView(QtWidgets.QListView(self))
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

    def checkedItems(self):
        checkedItems = []
        for index in range(self.count()):
            item = self.model().item(index)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                checkedItems.append(item)
        return checkedItems

class Ui_dialogCreateBatch(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialogCreateBatch):
        dialogCreateBatch.resize(400, 338)
        dialogCreateBatch.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(dialogCreateBatch)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 360, 115))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.cboItemList = CheckableComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.cboItemList.setObjectName("cboItemList")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.cboItemList, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        data = ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')

        for index, element in enumerate(data):
            self.cboItemList.addItem(element)
            item = self.cboItemList.model().item(index, 0)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(dialogCreateBatch)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 300, 156, 23))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(dialogCreateBatch)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialogCreateBatch)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialogCreateBatch):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        dialogCreateBatch.setWindowTitle(_translate("dialogCreateBatch", "Create Item Batch"))

class DialogCreateBatch(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_dialogCreateBatch):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.on_accepted)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def on_accepted(self):
        selectedItems = self.cboItemList.checkedItems()
        print(selectedItems)
        self.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DialogCreateBatch()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks! I have added the QListView it works. For cboMulSup, It was my mistake while refracting I should have changed it. And you recommending me to not to edit Qt Designer, since lack of my knowledge in Qt Designer i couldn't achieve this checkable comboBox.

Comment: i'm confused why we need to use one more class DialogCreateBatch. is that to keep custom comboBox and ui_Dialog object integrated?

Comment: If you could help me on keeping dropDown displayed allowing user to select some more from the list until he/she moves to next, this would be more complete.